# Java: JPQL date function to add a time period to another date

Tags: java, date, documentation, jpql

```
SELECT x FROM SomeClass
WHERE x.dateAtt BETWEEN CURRENT_DATE AND (CURRENT_DATE + 1 MONTH)
```

In the above JPQL statement, SomeClass has a memebr `dateAttr`, which is a `java.util.Date` and has a `@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)` annotation.

I need a way to do the `(CURRENT_DATE + 1 MONTH)` bit - it is obviously wrong in its current state - but cannot find the doc with the date function for JPQL.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a doc that **documents JPQL date functions** (and also how to do this particular query)?

Comment: Is this a query in some method you want? Or does this need to be in a trigger on the entity bean it self? IE: `@PrePersist` or `@PreUpdate`?

Comment: @Shervin : No, the query does not need to be performed in either `@PrePersist` or `@PreUpdate`. The query is a named query on a JPA Entity class (`SomeClass`).

Comment: @Shervin : Also, I know that I can use Java to compute the `Date` manipulations and then pass it into the query using a `:parameter`, however, I would much rather do it in the JPQL itself and avoid that unnecessary code.

Comment: I see, because thats what I would have suggested to do as a workaround.
I am not sure these functions are a part of the JPA standards. Which database are you using?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you have a date object that is + 1 month already you could do something like this:

```
public List findEmployees(Date endDate) {
  return entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT e from Employee e WHERE e.startDate BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2")
    .setParameter(1,new Date(), TemporalType.DATE)
    .setParameter(2,endDate, TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
}
```

This however, requires that the dates be valid before hand.

**UPDATE**

If you always want the next month, you can use [JodaTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net) which has a great and easy api.
You could then modify your query like this:

```
//Get next month
DateTime dt = new DateTime();
entityManager.createQuery(
"SELECT e from Employee e WHERE e.startDate BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2")
.setParameter(1,new Date(), TemporalType.DATE)
.setParameter(2,dt.plusMonths(1).toDate(), TemporalType.DATE).getResultList();
```

Comment: Did you try the JodaTime part? Can JPA deal with a `DateTime`?

Comment: @Pascal: Good point. I forgot the toDate() method. This will return a `java.util.Date`

Comment: Slight improvement: `.setParameter(1, dt.toDate(), TemporalType.DATE)` (one import less and consistency with the next line)

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question "JPQL date functions" as JPQL is a query specification by itself and the answers here are Java/JPA based solutions. Ways to get at the solution no doubt but ... again, I think the answer below "Standard JPQL does [not] support such operations on dates" is more correct.

Answer (score 22):

Standard JPQL doesn't support such operations on dates. You will have to either use a native query or to do the computation on the Java side.

Comment: Is this still true?

Answer (score 5):

Or use commons-lang instead of jodatime:

```
entityManager.createQuery(
    "SELECT e from Employee e WHERE e.startDate BETWEEN ?1 AND ?2"
)
.setParameter(1,new Date(), TemporalType.DATE)
.setParameter(2,DateUtils.addMonths(new Date(), 1), TemporalType.DATE)
.getResultList();
```

But I know this is not what you are asking and I'm pretty sure it can't be done in JPQL alone, you will either have to pass a parameter or use a native named query

Comment: `DateUtils`? Is that part of std JDK or is it a library like Joda time?

Comment: it's in apache commons / lang, an open source library that is used internally by many frameworks: http://commons.apache.org/lang/

Comment: Better to use Joda-Time because its a reference implementation of JSR-310 (https://jsr-310.dev.java.net/)

Comment: true, but in most projects I have worked in, commons / lang was already in the classpath. And I don't think simple usage as seen above justifies the use of joda (if not used otherwise)

Answer (score -1):

Dears,

i'm using spring data, the entity save the createdDate as datetime, and in the repository like this:

```
@Query(value="SELECT t FROM MyEntity t WHERE t.createdDate Between ?1 and ?2")
public List<MyEntity> findAllBetweenDates(Calendar from, Calendar to);
```

so i can't use :

```
setParameter(1,new Date(), TemporalType.DATE
```

in the backend bean i use the following:

```
    //to set zero of hours,minutes,seconds and milliseconds
    fromCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    fromCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    fromCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    fromCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

    toCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.HOUR, 0);
    toCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
    toCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    toCalendar.set(java.util.Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
    // add 1 days and decrease 1 millisecond
    toCalendar.add(java.util.Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    toCalendar.add(java.util.Calendar.MILLISECOND, -1);

    allEntities = myEntityRepository.findAllBetweenDates(fromCalendar, toCalendar);
}
```

and it's working fine.