# How to query data base on Date, but your DB store date as date + time. 

Tags: java, datetime, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

Since I want to store date and time for each data in table `X`, I use

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateProcess;    //java.util.Date
```

and this work great. But now I want to create query that return all data in the same date. So I try

```
SELECT c from X c where c.dateProcess = : dateProcess
```

then I would pass in a `java.util.Date` for parameter `dateProcess`, but the returned result List is empty. I guess it must be that `time` comes into place here. So if the two dates does not have the exact date and time, it would not be equal, that would explain why my returned result list is empty. So how do I return a List of data base on a Date (dont care about time) in this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use a date range, specify the start and end time. > startTime and < endTime

Comment: Thank you. This answer my question. I posted these two links here showing specific instructions on how achieve what you suggested above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6611908/java-util-date-jodatime-given-a-java-util-date-generate-a-start-and-end-of-that and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856386/java-jpql-date-function-to-add-a-time-period-to-another-date

Answer (score 1):

Try [`TemporalType.DATE`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html#DATE)

If you need to retain the time, but only query for the date, then you have options:

- use JPQL date function - `day(..)`, `months(..)`, `year(..)`
- use `<` and `>` for date ranges (as James suggested)
- store the date and time in two different columns.

Comment: Sorry, I was busy the past couples days so I could not answer quick enough, and for it I apologize. If I switch to `TemporalType.Date`, do I lose the `time`? I want the date to display time in it as well.

Comment: yes, you lose it. But you can store it in a different column, I guess. See updated

Comment: would it be possible if I can ask you to show me a sample JPQL query using day(), months(), year() function?

Comment: it's as if they are sql functions - use them with the field as argument to extract the day, month and year

Answer (score 0):

Does specifiying [temporal type](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/TemporalType.html) as `Date` help or would you lose precision?

Comment: I would lose my `time` precision if I switch over TemporalType.Date

Answer (score 0):

Currently I do like this

[Using HQL to query on a date while ignoring the time on Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980366/using-hql-to-query-on-a-date-while-ignoring-the-time-on-oracle)

I haven't try this one yet. So not sure it will work. date_format is registered function in release.

http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/hibernate/dialect/MySQLDialect.java.html