# java.util.Date/JodaTime: Given a java.util.Date, generate a start and end of that given date

Tags: java, date, jpa, jodatime

If I was to given a specific java.util.Date, how can I generate a start and end of that given date. For example, I my date is `August 25, 2011`, then my start date would be `August 25, 2011 00 00 00` and my end of date would be `August 25, 2011 23 59 59`

**Background**: (Read below if you want to know why I ask this question)

I use JPA to map `date` to my MySql database like this. I want the `date` to have time as well, so I use `TemoporalType.TIMESTAMP`

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
private Date dateProcess; //java.util.Date
```

I need to query all data given a specific date, and since `date` is stored as above, I need a date range to achieve what I want.

My game plan is to convert `java.util.Date` to `JodaTime#DateTinme`, then construct the start and end date there, and convert it back **so that I can pass as parameters to JPQL**. But it seems that JodaTime is very immutable, I cant seem to see a setter method any where.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` represents an *instant* in time, with no reference to a time zone or calendar. The same instant will have a very different start/end of day depending on the time zone of the observer.

You could do something like:

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date.getTime(), timeZone);
LocalDate localDate = dateTime.ToLocalDate();

DateTime startOfDay = localDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(timeZone);
DateTime startOfNextDay = localDate.plusDays(1).toDateTimeAtStartOfDay(timeZone);
```

From the last two variables, you can get back to `java.util.Date` values if you want. Usually they'll both be midnight, but they *might* not be.

Note that you should use the start of the next day in an exclusive way, rather than the last second of the current day in an inclusive way, in order to avoid missing values such as August 25, 2011 23:59:59.500...

Comment: `date.getDate()`, is the `date` there `java.util.Date`? If so then isn't `date.getDate()` deprecated already, Jon? Shouldnt it be `date.getTime()`?

Comment: @Harry: Sorry, I meant `date.getTime()` - the way to get the `long` value in millis, basically.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the type you want is `DateMidnight`. Make a new `DateMidnight` and pass it the `DateTime` in question, and it will take the date at midnight in the morning of the same day. You could then also use the `plusDays()` function to add 1 day to get your end time.

Comment: I tend to avoid `DateMidnight`, as not every day in every time zone even *has* a midnight. `LocalDate.toDateTimeAtStartOfDay` is a better call IMO.

Comment: Cool -- I haven't used that before. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
Date date; // your date

Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTime(date);

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Date startDate = calendar.getTime();

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 23);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
Date endDate = calendar.getTime();
```

Comment: That's assuming the system time zone is the right one... I'd also suggest using Joda Time as a *much* nicer API...