# Hibernate Query to Show one week data?

Tags: sql, hibernate

How to write query in `Hibernate SQL` or `HSQL` to show one week data or 1month data from current date?

Comment: Already answered at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856386/java-jpql-date-function-to-add-a-time-period-to-another-date

Answer (score 0):

Consider an Entity Product with _productId and _productCreatedDate 
So the

```
StringBulider sql=new StringBuilder();
sql.append("select _productId,_productCreatedDate from Product where");
sql.append("_productCreatedDate between :currentDate and :dateOneMonthBefore")
sessionFactory.getSession().createQuery(sql.toString()).setParameter("currentDate",newDate())
 .setParameter("dateOneMonthBefore",new Date("Enter the month before the current date"))
```